# I have an if else statement that I dont know how to make the else part relevent

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

```js
const newInput = document.querySelector('input');
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



newInput.addEventListener('change', function(){

    if (newInput != ''){
     h1.innerText = 'Welcome ' + newInput.value
    } else {
    h1.innerText = 'Enter Your Username';
    }
});
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Input Event</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
    <!-- <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script> -->


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enter Your Username</h1>
    <input type="text" id="username">

    <script src="InputEvent.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My if else statement appears to be ignored unless I change it to (if (newInput === '*a value*' ) at which point it stops the function.

I don't understand why I can make the if statement relevant but it wont continue to the else part of the code.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `.value` property for `newInput.value`. `newInput` is a DOM node and you need to check if the value is empty.

```js
const newInput = document.querySelector('input');
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



newInput.addEventListener('change', function() {

  if (newInput.value !== '') {
    h1.innerText = 'Welcome ' + newInput.value
  } else {
    h1.innerText = 'Enter Your Username';
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Input Event</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Enter Your Username</h1>
  <input type="text" id="username">

  <script src="InputEvent.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not accessing the value correctly. You either need  newInput.value or event.target.value to get the value of the input. Working example of the specified problem https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-forest-18vme?file=/InputEvent.js:287-328